# functions calling in queue including callback using jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

In my application, I am doing some animation using `.animate()` on an event with `callback`. If the event fires rapidly, let say 5 times in half of second, how can I `queue` all events that are fired because in my `callback` function, a variable is updating itself and I want updated value in the next event fired.

My animate function is here :

```
function animateOnTouch() {
    $(this).animate({
        left : width*number
    },600,"linear",function(){
        updateNumber();    // updating the variable number
    });
}
```

I am not getting updated value when animateOnTouch fired second time in less than 600 milliseconds.

Comment: Show `updateNumber()` source, please.

Comment: It can be anything, say `number++`, My actual function is quite different.

Comment: You are updating your `number` only when animation is complete. Try to update it on animation start.

Comment: No, i need to update it only after animation complete, there is some functionality that are only possible after animation complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery way** (using [`jQuery.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)):

```
function animateOnTouch() {
    var self = this;
    $(this).queue(function () {
        $(self).animate({
            left : width*number
        }, 600, "linear", function() {
            updateNumber();
            $(self).dequeue();
        });
    });
}
```

Example **plain JS** approach:

```
var animationInProgress = false;
function animateOnTouch() {
    if (animationInProgress) {
        queueAnimation();
    } else {
        animate();
    }
}
function animate() {
    animationInProgress = true;
    obj.animate({
        left : width*number
    }, 600, "linear", function() {
        updateNumber();
        animateAllQueued(function () {
            animationInProgress = false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanx vbo, but how I implement `queueAnimation()` function, and `animateAllQueued`, one approach, I know, is to use `push()` and `shift()` method. Is it better? or any other approach?

Comment: Oh, it does not really matter in this case. You can even stick with incrementing/decrementing some counter. BTW, check my updated answer, just came up with jQuery approach.